# Sublime Text snippet packages not working

Tags: plugins, ide, sublimetext2

I'm using Sublime Text 2 for a while now, with many packages saving me a lot of time in production. However, I never dived into the way snippets and plugins in ST2 work.

There is a problem : trying to call the Bootstrap official plugin to get a snippet, I don't get any entries with the usual keywords. Browsing the installed, then enabled packages, I saw the plugin as if everything was running normally.

I deleted the other available bootstrap plugin I installed in order to avoid possible conflicts, and tried to disable, uninstall / install, enable the plugin again, then restarting ST2, in vain.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what the problem here is but I'll suggest cloning the repository into your packages folder

```
git clone git@github.com:devtellect/sublime-twitter-bootstrap-snippets.git
```